# Ender 3 Inconsistent Bad Prints

Tags: print-quality, creality-ender-3, troubleshooting

Recently, my Ender 3 printer is giving these bad quality prints as shown in the image below. Something in common in all these bad prints is that they only fail in a particular section. The print looks good on the rest of the parts. I'm having trouble on how to find people with similar problems as I don't know what type of failure this is called. I would really appreciate any suggestions on how to fix this or if anyone experienced the same issue and managed to solve this.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! Are your belts tight?

Comment: Looks underextruded from bad temperature to me

Comment: I agree with @Trish, very similar to an under extrusion issue I had with my Ender 3. In my particular case it was because the nozzle was clogged.

Comment: I'm with @0scar, looks like a belt is loose.